# Load select options on typing bootstrap select , jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a select box/dropdown/combobox which contains more than 14000 options it takes a long time to load these options when going to use it i'm using bootstrap select library for searching on options

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

how to load on typing in search box or load 100 option only and load others on scroll or any other option to load it quickly.

this is the code

```
<div class="form-group select-group">
           <label>{{trans('home.diag_name')}}</label>
            {!! Form::select('diagnosis',$diagnosis,$v->Diagnosis->id,['class'=>'form-control selectpicker','data-live-search' => 'true' , 'title' => 'Select a Diagnosis']) !!}
          </div>
```

i'm using laravel 5.2

Comment: Can you add the input data structure?

Comment: what about this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

Comment: @PraneshRavi done

Answer (score 0):

better than using library select2 :

on this link and ajax method  : https://select2.github.io/